# How can I perform this MySQL partitoning?

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning

I have a table with an integer column ranging from 1 to 32 (this column identify the type of record stored).

The types 5 and 12 represents 70% of the total number of rows, and this number is greater than 1M rows, so it seems to makes sense to partition the table.

Question is: how can I create a set of 3 partitions, one containing the type 5 records, the second containing the type 12 records, and the third one with the remaining records?

Comment: " it seems to makes sense to partition the table". Are you having some real problems with it, or did you just get this idea from the internet?

Comment: 1 million rows and you already want to partition..

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-list.html

```
create table some_table (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    some_id INT NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY LIST(some_id) (
    PARTITION fives VALUES IN (5),
    PARTITION twelves VALUES IN (12),
    PARTITION rest VALUES IN (1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Partition by list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-list.html)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that `type` is an index, then MySQL has already logically partitioned the table for you. Unless you really need physical partitioning, it seems to me you are only making trouble for yourself.